# React form not calling submit function upon submit button click

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I have a straight forward react form below which called a handlesubmit function when the submit button is clicked. However, it seems that there are two issues. Firstly, the form doesn't validate inputs, and in fact accepts the empty inputs when submitted. Any help is appreciated please.

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col"
import { useState } from "react"


const Register = () => {

    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        console.log("in handlesubmit: " + form.checkValidity())
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
    
        setValidated(true);
        console.log("in handlesubmit: " + validated)
      };

    console.log('First Name: ' + firstName);
    console.log('Last Name: ' + lastName);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Registration page</h1>
            <Form noValidated validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{textAlign:'left'}}>
            <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridFirstName">
                <Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" value={firstName} onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridLastName">
                <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" value={lastName} onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to add an onclick to your button. Try `onClick={()=>{}}` and see if that's triggers your form onsubmit?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Turns out it was because I forgot to add the actual validation check. Function was in fact being called and the form was submitted and page reloaded.